# How to fix gnome control center (monitor submenu) showing duplicate refresh rates

Tags: xrandr, gnome-control-center

My gnome-control-center show up duplicate refresh rates, like: 50Hz,50Hz; 59,54Hz/59,54Hz; 60Hz,60Hz ... (under xorg, wayland no issue)

xrandr command returns fine refresh rates for specified display.

Any idea???